# How do I use the requests module within Pycharm?

Tags: python

I'm new to Python, and I'm working in Pycharm to read data line by line from a webpage. For this task, I'm attempting to use the requests module. However, when I try to print the response object, I see "Process finished with exit code 0" and no object displayed.

Do I need to create some sort of setting to be able to work with HTTP requests in Python?

Code:

```py
import re
import requests 

def find_phone_number(url='https://www.python-course.eu/barneyhouse.txt'):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response


    print(find_phone_number(url='https://www.python-course.eu/barneyhouse.txt'))
```

Comment: Please attach your code to the body of your question instead of a picture of it

Comment: Also it doesn't look like you ever call the function later on in your code

Comment: https://repl.it/join/ldzollgb-ivanbarayev you can check this example

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Are you sure you got the tabbing right? Double-check the last line. That syntax does not look good to me. Try untabbing that line.

Comment: @CFV I untabbed it, and it worked to get the contents of the url. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call the function and access the 'text' element.

Also, in your code the print statement is not indented properly so it will never be run.

Here is an example of the code doing what I think you intendend:

```
import re
import requests 

def find_phone_number(url='https://www.python-course.eu/simpsons_phone_book.txt'):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response
    
text_you_want = find_phone_number().text
print(text_you_want)
```

Comment: No comment on that last line not being runnable?

Comment: After the return statement

Answer (score 1):

Well, for starters, your `find_phone_number()` function calls itself after it returns. This is because your last line is indented and therefore inside the function definition. The reason you keep getting `Process finished with exit code 0` is because your function is never actually called. This should work:

```
import re
import requests 

def find_phone_number(url='https://www.python-course.eu/barneyhouse.txt'):
    response = requests.get(url)
    return response

print(find_phone_number(url='https://www.python-course.eu/barneyhouse.txt'))
```